# Cant access [DjangoFilterBackend] in APIVIEW of django rest frame work

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to access filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend] in my APIVIEW class but it is not working, it is working in generics api views tho, what could be the reason?

```
 class ListDocuments(generics.ListAPIView):
     filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
     filterset_fields = [ 'name']


     model = Document
     serializer_class = DocumentSerializer

#     def get_queryset(self):
#         return Document.objects.all()
```

Comment: The `filter_backends` is written in comment?

Comment: No, I accidently posted it it isnt in my code and still not working